# Show only certain dimensions of the web page in UIWebView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

How can I show only part of the page that a UIWebView has loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure there is a solution which is straight-forward. I'd suggest one of the following (assuming I'm reading the question right)...

(1) Get the web server to serve up a custom page which only contains what you need

or...

(2) Grab the data from the web, modify it to only include what you need and then display it using UIWebView.

What exactly is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I had to download the page from my client's site (since I don't have the privileges to edit it, and I'm not a web developer, so it would be kind of difficult for me to detect the device being used and design the page accordingly), modify it with Dreamweaver and upload it to my site. It ended up working out fine.